# on_delete error for Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm currently doing some projects from a book called Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes. Currently, I'm doing lab 19.1 where I have to use previous code to make a Django project while changing some of his own code but ran into a problem.
Every time I want to run this command

```
>>>python manage.py makemigration blogs
```

in return, I get this code

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'on_delete'

His original models.py code:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

and my current code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Post(models.Model):
    """SThe post"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) >= 50:
            """Return a string represerntation of the model"""
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

I honestly do not know why I'm getting this error code I've check to see if I messed something up but I cannot find anything. Is there anyone that may know?

Comment: check if this monkey-patch is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776076/django-1-to-django-2-on-delete-error/63111357#63111357

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 2.x, [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) is required. This is from the Django 2.0 relase notes:

> The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now
>   required in models and migrations. Consider squashing migrations so
>   that you have fewer of them to update.

Therefore, the error comes from this line:

```
topic = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost)
```

You're creating a Foreign key relationship without providing the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) property. So, follow the link and pick the one that suits your needs.

Comment: But why did it work when i type everything like he did and then when i decided to change a model name it brings me up with that error

Comment: What Django version are you using ?

Comment: I was using 1.11.7 before so i guess that they released an update

Comment: In your python console run `import django` and then `django.VERSION`

Comment: (1, 11, 7, 'final', 0)

Comment: Is it probably because i created a virtual environment for it and install django in it

Comment: Check the version in your virtualenv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160552/discussion-between-choloboy-and-scharette).