# Django 1 to Django 2 on_delete error

Tags: python, django, workflow

I believe this workflow was created for a previous Django version. Now when I am trying to upgrade it I get an error to add on_delete. Here is what I have done but it is still not working and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

ORIGINAL

```
class Task(AbstractEntity):
    request = ForeignKey(Request, related_name='tasks')   
    assignee = ForeignKey(Group)    
    updated_by = ForeignKey(User)    
    activity_ref = CharField(max_length=100)    
    status = CharField(verbose_name="Status", max_length=30, choices=TASK_STATUS)
```

MY VERSION

```
class Task(models.AbstractEntity):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = ForeignKey(Group)
    updated_by = ForeignKey(User)
    activity_ref = CharField(max_length=100)
    status = CharField(verbose_name="Status", max_length=30, choices=TASK_STATUS)
```

Then I get another error saying the model is not defined.

Comment: *ALL* foreign key fields need the `on_delete` parameter. You should add it to `assignee` and `updated_by` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you mean like this? class Task(models.AbstractEntity):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    updated_by =models. ForeignKey(User)
    activity_ref = CharField(max_length=100)
    status = CharField(verbose_name="Status", max_length=30, choices=TASK_STATUS)

Comment: No, that is exactly the same as what you posted above.

Comment: Err.. `on_delete` paramater is still missing on the FK fields `assignee` and `updated_by`

Comment: Thank you both so much, I really appreciate it. Sorry I am new at python and Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Django 2.0 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (and also the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)) all `Foreignkey` fields now have a required `on_delete` parameter.

It seems to be missing on your model's fields. The release notes also advise to take a look at your migrations:

> The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now required in models and migrations. Consider squashing migrations so that you have fewer of them to update.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this.

If you have lots and lots of table which needs adding "on_delete" parameter where ever Foreign-key or One-to-One key is used.. then going through all the models to add on_delete parameter would be very hectic.
You can perform monkey-patch of foreign key to achieve your goal.

add the below monkey patch file in your project settings folder:

> monkey_patches.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ForeignKey, OneToOneRel
from django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors import ReverseOneToOneDescriptor, ForwardOneToOneDescriptor
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class ForeignKeyMonkeyPatch(ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, to, on_delete=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(to, on_delete, *args, **kwargs)


class OneToOneFieldMonkeyPatch(ForeignKeyMonkeyPatch):
    many_to_many = False
    many_to_one = False
    one_to_many = False
    one_to_one = True

    related_accessor_class = ReverseOneToOneDescriptor
    forward_related_accessor_class = ForwardOneToOneDescriptor
    rel_class = OneToOneRel

    description = _("One-to-one relationship")

    def __init__(self, to, on_delete=None, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['unique'] = True
        super().__init__(to, on_delete, *args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if "unique" in kwargs:
            del kwargs['unique']
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        if self.remote_field.parent_link:
            return None
        return super().formfield(**kwargs)

    def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
        if isinstance(data, self.remote_field.model):
            setattr(instance, self.name, data)
        else:
            setattr(instance, self.attname, data)

    def _check_unique(self, **kwargs):
        # Override ForeignKey since check isn't applicable here.
        return []




setattr(models, 'ForeignKey', ForeignKeyMonkeyPatch)
setattr(models, 'OneToOneField', OneToOneFieldMonkeyPatch)
```

Now, call this file in your project settings...

> from .monkey_patches import *

The above code will reset the **ForeignKey** and **OneToOneField** with our monkey-patched classes, thereby setting **on_delete** as **None** by default

*P.S. (you can even create an app (named "monkey_patches" or anything that you desire..) and add the above code in models.py)*